# Visual Studio 2019 show implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Now I'm using JetBrains Rider and I can see source code most of the objects with Ctrl+B. I can see how ConcurrentQuery works inside, how works DbContext and all other staff. It takes several seconds to get source code.
Is there a way to get the same behavior with Visual Studio 2019? VS show only interface of object

This is Ctrl+B on Dictionary in Rider:

[image]
All private fields and implementations.

This is Goto Implementaion in VS:
[image]

GoTo Definition in VS:
[image]
Only public and without any source;

Answer (score -1):

Right click -> go to Implementation

Comment: No. Thats do nothing.

Comment: Try install Resharper (https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/resharper/). It adds most of the Rider functionality to vs.